# ElasticSearch Log Histogram

Tags: elasticsearch

I want log-width bins in Elasticsearch. How can I do this? I know how to use the normal histogram in Elasticsearch DSL,

```
 = Search(using=client, index="cms*").filter('range', CpuEff={'from':0, 'to':100})
    s.aggs.bucket(vname, 'histogram', field=vname, interval=10)
    aggs = s.execute().aggregations
```

But some of my data is poorly represented like this, so I want to do it with a log scale on the x-axis.

I mean that I want bins like [(1, 10), (10, 100), (100, 1000), ...]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/search-aggregations-bucket-variablewidthhistogram-aggregation.html

Then what you can do is:

```
"variable_width_histogram": {
  "field": "price",
  "script": "Math.log10(_value)",
  "buckets": 20 //number of buckets you want
}
```

You will get 20 buckets with "key" inside them thats log10.

Than just do Math.pow(10, key) to get the value